# In Java8 Collections How Map to Store Duplicate Key and Different Value

Tags: java

I have a string which are separated by ":" , In java 8+ how to split the string and store in Map.

String Str = "Member:Test1,Member:Test2,Induction:Value,Name:Sam,Name:Sun"

The Java map should hold the Key as Member and value as Test1,Test2 and Name as Key and value as Sam,Sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a `Map<String, List<String>>` as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Member:Test1,Member:Test2,Induction:Value,Name:Sam,Name:Sun";
        String[] arr = str.split(",");
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : arr) {
            String[] keyVal = s.split(":");
            if (keyVal.length == 2) {
                List<String> list = map.get(keyVal[0]);
                if (list == null) {
                    map.put(keyVal[0], new ArrayList<>(List.of(keyVal[1])));
                } else {
                    list.add(keyVal[1]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Induction=[Value], Member=[Test1, Test2], Name=[Sam, Sun]}
```

The logic is to split the string on `,`. Then, iterate the resulting array and split each string from the array again on `:`. This gives the key and the value to be added to the `List`. If the `List` already exists, add the value to it or instantiate a new `List` with the value.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this behavior you could think to use Apache commons collections.

```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
       <version>4.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

And use MultivaluedMap.

Answer (score 0):

## Unique keys

A [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) cannot store multiple entries using the same key, by definition.

To quote the second sentence of the Javadoc:

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

Answer (score 0):

For duplicates you can use LinkedList, Stack or ArrayDeque.

Map and Set does not store duplicate key values.